# Collect customer credit card and start a subscription later with Laravel Cashier

Tags: laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

For some business reasons, I need to collect customers credit card data and start the subscription at a later (unknown) date. The reason is because we need to proceed to some verification before actually starting the subscription. Thus I can not use the trialDays() method.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

That's actually the more common way to do this.  Simply collect the payment details and create a token (or source) using your front-end.  Then attach that token (or source) as a payment method on the customer record using the [Create Card API Method](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card).